# Allow Cachet to run with other sites

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have installed the open source status page Cachet on my macbook's local web server and it works perfectly but during the set up it tells you to change your apache's virtual host to route all traffic to Cachet. I am trying to allow Cachet to run by going to the main domain but if I go to domain/test I would like it to go to another web page. I tried adding another vhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://domain/test
DocumentRoot /Users/macbook/Sites/
</VirtualHost>
```

but this does not work, I just get error 404 when trying to reach /test page.

Answer (score 0):

[Cachet](https://github.com/CachetHQ/Cachet) is built using the [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) framework, so there is a front controller in the `public/` directory. That's why you need to route all the requests to this file. But **you do not need to route all the traffic of your server to Cachet**, that's just the traffic of the site (Cachet), in order to `/setup` and others are executed by `/public/index.php`.

Your vhost file may be simple, below an example of what it could be.
It is a simple vhost configured in Mamp, on OSX.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Cachet/public"
  ServerName status.mysite.com
  <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Cachet/public>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The routing to the `public/index.php` file is performed by a `.htaccess` file, so you don't have to write this configuration in your vhost. All you need to do in your vhost is to allow the `.htaccess` execution.

> **Note for local web server**
>   If you want to use a custom domain name, you'll need to
>   update the `/etc/hosts` file to match the domain with your loopback IP
>   address.